# Read JSON objects from a file and pass each of them to cURL

Tags: shell, curl, xargs

I have a file `access.log` containing timestamps and JSON objects delimited by a newline:

```json
09:52:11 { "key1": "value", "key2": 2, "key3": true }\n
09:52:13 { "key4": "value2", "key5": 5, "key6": false }\n
09:55:33 { "key7": "value7", "key8": 8, "key9": true }\n
...
```

I need to read the file line by line, extract JSON objects and pass each of them as a request body to cURL. I tried to solve the problem with [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) but it passes `{}` to the request body:

```bash
cat access.log | cut -c10- | xargs -0 -I {} curl -X POST-H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/ -d '{}'
cat access.log | cut -c10- | xargs -0 -I {} curl -X POST-H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/ -d {}
```

I have a mistake somewhere in the syntax. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: `\n` is not a literal value. So by issuing `cat access.log` the result is:

```json
09:52:11 { "key1": "value", "key2": 2, "key3": true }
09:52:13 { "key4": "value2", "key5": 5, "key6": false }
09:55:33 { "key7": "value7", "key8": 8, "key9": true }
...
```

Comment: Is `\n` included in log as literal values?

Comment: Nope, my bad. I wanted to indicate a new line. I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat access.log | sed 's/\\n//g' > access_temp.log
echo ""
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    json_string=$(echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | jq -c .)
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json_string" http://localhost:8080/api/
done < "access_temp.log"
rm access_temp.log
```

The sed in the beginning was because the '\n' was messing up the jq command, so I had to remove it.

You can add echos, or set -x in the beginning to check the values being passed.

Comment: That worked in both cases: with `\n` at the end of the lines and without it. `sed` does its job. Thanks.

Comment: yes, since `sed` wont replace anything if it didnt find the `\n`. Happy to help :).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass -0 to xargs - it makes it expect zero character as a separator. Since you don't have zero character it treats all input as one record and passes it all to curl. Removing the -0 fixes it.
In addition, `-I` option makes xarg to use newlines as a delimiter, instead of spaces.

It is easier to see with echo i/o curl. Compare output from
`cat aa.log | cut -c10- | xargs -0 -I {} echo %%'{}'%%` which is

```
%%{ "key1": "value", "key2": 2, "key3": true }
{ "key4": "value2", "key5": 5, "key6": false }
{ "key7": "value7", "key8": 8, "key9": true }
%%
```

To output from `cat aa.log | cut -c10- | xargs -I {} echo %%'{}'%%` which is

```
%%{ key1: value, key2: 2, key3: true }%%
%%{ key4: value2, key5: 5, key6: false }%%
%%{ key7: value7, key8: 8, key9: true }%%
```

P.S. Also, you can use `-t` option to see the command that xargs builds

Comment: I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work - wrap `xargs` with a light-weight shell such as `dash` :

```
 printf '%s' '
     09:52:11 { "key1": "value",  "key2": 2, "key3": true  }\n
     09:52:13 { "key4": "value2", "key5": 5, "key6": false }\n
     09:55:33 { "key7": "value7", "key8": 8, "key9": true  }\n' | 

 mawk NF=NF FS='^[^{]*' OFS= ORS='\0' | 

 xargs -0 dash -v -x -c '
  
    for __; do 

        curl -s -X POST-H '\''Content-Type: application/json'\'' \
                     --url '\''https://localhost:8080/api'\'' -d "$__"

    done ' _
```

> 

```
+ curl -s -X POST-H Content-Type: application/json --url 
  https://localhost:8080/api -d { "key1": "value", "key2": 2, "key3": true }
+ curl -s -X POST-H Content-Type: application/json --url 
  https://localhost:8080/api -d { "key4": "value2", "key5": 5, "key6": false }
+ curl -s -X POST-H Content-Type: application/json --url 
  https://localhost:8080/api -d { "key7": "value7", "key8": 8, "key9": true }
```

The `-v(erbose) -x(trace)` flags for `dash` are totally optional, and in this situation they could be a rough proxy for `xargs -t`.